# Is probability of default an elusive concept?

Tags: probability, credit-scoring

[Here](https://mx.nthu.edu.tw/%7Ejtyang/Teaching/Risk_management/Papers/Testing/Uses%20and%20Misuses%20of%20Measures%20for%20Credit%20Rating%20Accuracy.pdf), page 5, it is stated that *probability of default* is an elusive concept:

> Thus, the realization of the random variable "default of firm *n* at time *t*" is governed by its PD if a firm has survived until *t*-1. Therefore $\lambda_{nt}$ is the true but unknown probability of default of firm *n* at time *t*. As Hilden et al. (1978, p. 240) noted: "...[ $\lambda_{nt}$ ] is an elusive concept. However, given that such probabilities are thought to be conceptually well defined, there can be no disagreement that they are the unknown parameters which the assigned probabilities serve to estimate".

What is meant by *elusive*? Does the concept of *probability of default* differ from concepts of other *probabilities*?

Comment: How exactly would you ever discover or measure such a probability?  There is just one firm and one time and therefore no opportunity for true replication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a guess here, but I think what the authors may mean is that there are a lot of very influential factors that go into whether a firm will default, many of which are unknown. Which of these factors you know at the time of prediction will *greatly* influence the conditional probability of default.

For example, suppose you want to know whether a firm will default after 1 year. If all you know is age (i.e. 1 year), you will not have a very refined estimate. You may be be able to refine this more by knowing what type of business this is. And knowing what the debt to income ratio is will be more helpful. Knowing whether they were cooking the books for years will be very, very helpful.

In other words, the conditional probability of default is heavily influenced by what you are conditioning on. I'm guessing that predicting default may then be more "elusive" than other predictive problems because *what* we know about a particular firm when making a prediction can vary more, for example due to news reports, than more standard prediction problems where we're fine with always conditioning on the same information.

Answer (score 1):

Elusive means

> difficult to find, catch, or achieve

And so in light of this I believe the author may mean it is difficult to estimate (at least directly).